# Changing facealpha property causes figure to self-destruct

Tags: matlab, rendering, osx-snow-leopard

I'm running Matlab R2009b on Snow Leopard, and I am trying to create a transparent polygon.  The following line works fine:

> > figure,fill([1 0 0 1],[-1e-9 -1e-9 1e-9 1e-9],'r')

But when I set the transparency,

> > alpha(.5);

the figure collapses in on itself.  That is, any title, xlabel, and ylabel I have in the figure show up right in the middle and the polygon disappears.

I get the same results from

> > figure,fill([1 0 0 1],[-1e-9 -1e-9 1e-9 1e-9],'r','facealpha',.5)

and I get the same result when I manually set the facealpha to .5 in the figure editor.

But if the polygon is bigger it works fine:

> > figure,fill([1 0 0 1],[-1e-3 -1e-3 1e-3 1e-3],'r')
> >     alpha(.5);

Also, I tried it on a PC and it worked fine.

I think it must be a problem with the rendering.  My opengl version is:

> Version         = 2.1 NVIDIA-1.6.10
>   Vendor          = NVIDIA Corporation
>   Renderer        = NVIDIA GeForce 9400M OpenGL Engine
>   MaxTextureSize  = 8192
>   Visual          = 0x24 (TrueColor, depth 24, RGB mask 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff)
>   Software        = false
>   # of Extensions = 121

What can I do to get it to display properly?

Comment: Looks like a bug. I have the same behavior on Mac, MATLAB 2007b. No problem on PC.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out the Mathworks Bug Reports. I've only got a copy of MATLAB on PC, so I can't reproduce the error, but [this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/search_results?search_executed=1&keyword=255850&release_filter=Exists+in&release=174&selected_products=&commit=Search) known bug has a workaround. I'm not sure if that's what you're dealing with, or if it's something else, but you can browse more bug reports here: [Mathworks Bug Reports](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/)

Comment: Take note that you'll need a MathWorks account to get to the bug reports.